# GAE DataStore composite index not working/recognized

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I use GAE with Java, with Objectify for DataStore access.

Recently I added a query that filters an entity by two properties, in dev server it works without issues, but in production, the query failed with message telling that the indexes should be defined and also it suggested what the indexes are.
So I read more about the indexes and included the needed one in WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml , and made sure that the WAR contains the file as needed, however I still get the same error as the indexes file isn't actually there.

Entity1.java

```
@Entity
@Cache
class Entity1{
 @Index private String property1;
 @Index private String property2;

 @Index @Parent private Ref<ParentEntity> parent; 

 /* setters and getters */
}
```

datastore-indexes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Entity1" ancestor="true" source="manual">
        <property name="property1" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="property2" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My indexes did not work 'till I deployed them using `gcloud` via the command line (for PHP backend).

I found this line for Java, perhaps you should try running it and seeing if indexes show up in the DataStore>Indexes page.

`./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_indexes myapp/war`

Comment: I used gcloud command instead, but it just doesn't make sense they say it reads the indexes from WEB-INF/index.yaml and datastore-indexes.xml automatically.